# Process XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, excel-interop

Is there any library for processing the XML files that you get from the Range.Value property using the option XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet? Currently I simply process it as an XDocument.

If not, where can I find a specification of the file format?

Here is an example file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<ss:Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
 <ss:Styles>
  <ss:Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
   <ss:Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom" />
   <ss:Borders />
   <ss:Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#000000" />
   <ss:Interior />
   <ss:NumberFormat />
   <ss:Protection />
  </ss:Style>
  <ss:Style ss:ID="s16">
   <ss:Interior ss:Color="#FFFF00" ss:Pattern="Solid" />
  </ss:Style>
  <ss:Style ss:ID="s17">
   <ss:Interior ss:Color="#F2DCDB" ss:Pattern="Solid" />
  </ss:Style>
  <ss:Style ss:ID="s18">
   <ss:Interior ss:Color="#CCFFFF" ss:Pattern="Solid" />
  </ss:Style>
 </ss:Styles>
 <ss:Worksheet ss:Name="Blad1">
  <ss:Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="14" ss:ExpandedRowCount="20" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15">
   <ss:Row>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$A$1</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$B$1</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s16"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$C$1</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s16"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$D$1</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s16"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$E$1</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s16"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$F$1</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s16"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$G$1</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s16"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$H$1</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$I$1</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$J$1</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$K$1</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$L$1</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$M$1</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$N$1</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
   </ss:Row>
   <ss:Row>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$A$2</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$B$2</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s16"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$C$2</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s16"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$D$2</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s16"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$E$2</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s16"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$F$2</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s16"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$G$2</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s16"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$H$2</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$I$2</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$J$2</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$K$2</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$L$2</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$M$2</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$N$2</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
   </ss:Row>
   <ss:Row>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$A$3</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$B$3</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s16"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$C$3</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s16"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$D$3</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s16"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$E$3</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s16"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$F$3</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s16"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$G$3</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s16"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$H$3</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$I$3</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$J$3</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$K$3</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$L$3</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$M$3</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$N$3</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
   </ss:Row>
   <ss:Row>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$A$4</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$B$4</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$C$4</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$D$4</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$E$4</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$F$4</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$G$4</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$H$4</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$I$4</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$J$4</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$K$4</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$L$4</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$M$4</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$N$4</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
   </ss:Row>
   <ss:Row>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$A$5</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$B$5</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$C$5</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$D$5</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$E$5</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$F$5</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$G$5</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s18"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$H$5</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s18"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$I$5</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s18"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$J$5</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s18"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$K$5</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$L$5</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$M$5</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$N$5</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
   </ss:Row>
   <ss:Row>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$A$6</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$B$6</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$C$6</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$D$6</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$E$6</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$F$6</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$G$6</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s18"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$H$6</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s18"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$I$6</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s18"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$J$6</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s18"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$K$6</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$L$6</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$M$6</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$N$6</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
   </ss:Row>
   <ss:Row>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$A$7</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s17"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$B$7</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s17"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$C$7</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s17"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$D$7</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s17"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$E$7</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s17"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$F$7</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s17"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$G$7</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s18"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$H$7</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s18"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$I$7</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s18"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$J$7</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s18"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$K$7</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$L$7</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$M$7</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$N$7</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
   </ss:Row>
   <ss:Row>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$A$8</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s17"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$B$8</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s17"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$C$8</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s17"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$D$8</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s17"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$E$8</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s17"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$F$8</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s17"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$G$8</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s18"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$H$8</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s18"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$I$8</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s18"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$J$8</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s18"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$K$8</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$L$8</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$M$8</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$N$8</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
   </ss:Row>
   <ss:Row>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$A$9</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s17"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$B$9</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s17"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$C$9</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s17"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$D$9</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s17"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$E$9</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s17"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$F$9</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s17"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$G$9</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s18"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$H$9</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s18"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$I$9</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s18"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$J$9</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s18"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$K$9</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$L$9</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$M$9</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$N$9</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
   </ss:Row>
   <ss:Row>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$A$10</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s17"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$B$10</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s17"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$C$10</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s17"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$D$10</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s17"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$E$10</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s17"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$F$10</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s17"><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$G$10</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$H$10</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$I$10</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$J$10</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$K$10</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$L$10</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$M$10</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$N$10</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
   </ss:Row>
   <ss:Row>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$A$11</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$B$11</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$C$11</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$D$11</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$E$11</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$F$11</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$G$11</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$H$11</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$I$11</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$J$11</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$K$11</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$L$11</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$M$11</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$N$11</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
   </ss:Row>
   <ss:Row>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$A$12</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$B$12</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$C$12</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$D$12</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$E$12</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$F$12</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$G$12</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$H$12</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$I$12</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$J$12</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$K$12</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$L$12</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$M$12</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$N$12</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
   </ss:Row>
   <ss:Row>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$A$13</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$B$13</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$C$13</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$D$13</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$E$13</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$F$13</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$G$13</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$H$13</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$I$13</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$J$13</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$K$13</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$L$13</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$M$13</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$N$13</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
   </ss:Row>
   <ss:Row>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$A$14</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$B$14</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$C$14</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$D$14</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$E$14</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$F$14</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$G$14</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$H$14</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$I$14</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$J$14</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$K$14</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$L$14</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$M$14</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$N$14</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
   </ss:Row>
   <ss:Row>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$A$15</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$B$15</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$C$15</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$D$15</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$E$15</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$F$15</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$G$15</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$H$15</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$I$15</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$J$15</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$K$15</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$L$15</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$M$15</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$N$15</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
   </ss:Row>
   <ss:Row>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$A$16</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$B$16</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$C$16</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$D$16</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$E$16</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$F$16</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$G$16</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$H$16</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$I$16</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$J$16</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$K$16</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$L$16</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$M$16</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$N$16</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
   </ss:Row>
   <ss:Row>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$A$17</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$B$17</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$C$17</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$D$17</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$E$17</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$F$17</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$G$17</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$H$17</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$I$17</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$J$17</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$K$17</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$L$17</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$M$17</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$N$17</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
   </ss:Row>
   <ss:Row>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$A$18</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$B$18</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$C$18</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$D$18</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$E$18</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$F$18</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$G$18</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$H$18</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$I$18</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$J$18</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$K$18</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$L$18</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$M$18</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$N$18</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
   </ss:Row>
   <ss:Row>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$A$19</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$B$19</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$C$19</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$D$19</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$E$19</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$F$19</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$G$19</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$H$19</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$I$19</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$J$19</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$K$19</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$L$19</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$M$19</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$N$19</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
   </ss:Row>
   <ss:Row>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$A$20</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$B$20</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$C$20</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$D$20</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$E$20</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$F$20</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$G$20</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$H$20</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$I$20</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$J$20</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$K$20</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$L$20</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$M$20</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">$N$20</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
   </ss:Row>
  </ss:Table>
 </ss:Worksheet>
</ss:Workbook>
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140066(office.10).aspx is a specification, but perhaps there is a newer version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specification can be found in this MSDN article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140066(office.10).aspx

This library can be used to manipulate the files: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22935/A-Very-Easy-to-Use-Excel-XML-Import-Export-Library